# Django project printing to console instead of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

**What I'm trying to do:**

Translate input -> pig latin onclick and display output. See code below:

```
class translator:
    def pigLatin(sentence):
        translation = " "
        for word in sentence.split():
            if word[0] in "aeiou":
                translation += word + "yay "
            if word[0] and word[1] not in "aeiou":
                translation += word[2:] + word[0:2] + "ay"
                print("hai")
            else:
                translation +=  word[1:] + word[0] + "ay "
        return translation

    sentence = input("Enter word/sentence you want translated to pig latin below: ")

    print(pigLatin(sentence))
```

**What's happening:**

As soon as I run my local server, the above input prompt ^ appears in console, as seen below:

[translator running in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPJhc.png)

Problem being, I want this to appear in my browser onclick. Instead, when I click my "translate" button, it just repeats my translate div in the output section. (see below image for clarity.)

[translator in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivkC4.png)

**Other relevant code/file structure:**

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pigLatinApp import pigLatinTranslator

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pigLatinApp/home.html')

def output(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        py_obj = pigLatinTranslator.translator
        return render(request, 'pigLatinApp/home.html', {'output': py_obj})
```

**Templates**

*header.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pig Latin Translator</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="body">    

<section id="translatorSection">
<!------------------Log Sum Container-------------------------->
    <div class="container" id="translatorContainer">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>           
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

*home.html*

```
{% extends "pigLatinApp/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form>
            <h3>Pig Latin Translator</h3>
                <p>Enter below what you want translated!</p>
                <input type="string" class="form-control" placeholder="Type what you want translated here!">
                <button id="translateToPig" class="btn btn-success form-control">Translate</button>
                <div id="displayTranslation">

                </div>

        </form>     
    </div>   
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$("#translateToPig").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $.get("/output/", function(data) {
        $("#displayTranslation").html(data);
    }, "html");
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you issue a `print` command in your code, its output will be printed in the console of the development server. When programming with Django there isn't a need to use `print` in your code, except for debugging.

Using the Python built-in `input` is useful only on the command line. This method shouldn't be used for creating a web page.

If you want to get some user input in the browser, you can use django forms to process it.
You could make something like:

```
class TranslateForm(forms.Form):
    translation_input = forms.CharField()
```

then use the form in the view and get the user input.
Please check the official documentation for [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/).

You could skip the form, since it is just a single input field, and get the user input through the `request`. For this purpose the `<input>` element needs the attribute `name`. Then in the view (`def output`) you can access it through:

```
request.GET.get('name', None) # name is the value of attribute name
```

GET is the HTTP method, if you need change it to POST, but for your case GET is the appropriate method.

Comment: I tried using your request.GET method, but when I try to print the user's input in the console it returns "<function output at 0x000001EC5BZ58EA0>"? I appreciate your help